# Is there a one-click message delete option in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client, productivity

After having Gmail and Hotmail tabs hogging my Chrome browser w/ irrational memory consumption, I decided to try desktop email clients. Using Windows 10's native Mail app was fine, except for the fact that you cannot arrange the panes layout to have the preview pane under the messages list pane.

So, I installed Mozilla Thunderbird, and it is working fine. However, a few features that are available in the Web-based clients and the Mail app. The most prominent one is the lack of one-click message delete. That is, I receive lots of messages that I delete immediately (mostly automated emails), and with Thunderbird, I need to right-click on the message and then find the Delete entry in the long drop-down menu.

In the other clients, when you hover over a message, a trash icon appears that lets you delete it from the list in one click.

Is there a way to configure Thunderbird for one-click delete?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to configure Thunderbird for one-click delete [on Hover]?

There is not.  Currently, you must first select the message(s) to be deleted.  But you can multiselect and also filter + select which could expidite selection if you do this for multiple subjects.

However, if I were you. for messages that I routinely delete I would create a folder and a filter to automatically send them to the folder, review the folder every few days or once a week (or month), and delete multiple days of messages en masse.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware and using the multi-select option. I addition to the regularly generated messages there are other, non automated ones, so a filter does little here. And also, when you select the messages, the preview pane is updated with the last one selected in the group, which annoys by itself.